# Getting "The parameter is incorrect" when adding more than One table to DB Diagram

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

Using SQL SERVER 2016, Getting `The parameter is incorrect` exception when adding more than One table to DB Diagram. Behavior is as if there is a limit of only 1 table allowed.  I've tried repairing both SQL SERVER 2016 and SSMS.  After multiple reboots, still can not add more than one table to a DB Diagram.  My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: I have the same issue, for me, its only happens when two tables have a relationship, correct?

Comment: I also have this issue and it is only when adding two or more related tables. I also can't drag to create a relationship between two not related tables, it just silently fails. Anyone find a fix?

Comment: I have this problem too. It works on my laptop but does not work on my PC. Same Windows 10 version, same SQL 2016 version. My problem happens WHEN I try to create a relationship, and my database is brand new, no relationship already exists.

Comment: I have same issue . i tray to uninstall sql server and install again  But No result